# Mysqltuner optimize config and tables, report

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, report, mysqltuner

Report from mysqltuner, can you help me ? how to disable InnoDB ist last Linux debian mysql version on stable, and conection aborted on more than 30%?

```
[!!] InnoDB is enabled but isn't being used
[OK] Total fragmented tables: 0

-------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 13h 49m 59s (18K q [0.368 qps], 2K conn, TX: 5M, RX: 1M)
[--] Reads / Writes: 63% / 37%
[--] Total buffers: 176.0M global + 2.7M per thread (25 max threads)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 243.2M (23% of installed RAM)
[!!] Slow queries: 7% (1K/18K)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 20% (5/25)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 8.0M/185.0K
[OK] Key buffer hit rate: 96.0% (27K cached / 1K reads)
[OK] Query cache efficiency: 41.0% (3K cached / 8K selects)
[OK] Query cache prunes per day: 0
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (0 temp sorts / 291 sorts)
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 25% (204 on disk / 794 total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (5 created / 2K connections)
[!!] Table cache hit rate: 2% (64 open / 2K opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 9% (94/1K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 99% (9K immediate / 9K locks)
[!!] Connections aborted: 32%

-------- Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Add skip-innodb to MySQL configuration to disable InnoDB
    MySQL started within last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
    Increase table_open_cache gradually to avoid file descriptor limits
    Read this before increasing table_open_cache over 64: http://bit.ly/1mi7c4C
    Your applications are not closing MySQL connections properly
Variables to adjust:
    table_open_cache (> 64)
```

Answer (score 0):

Innodb is needed in the last MySQL version 5.6 as default engine.

aborted connections is > 0, this mmeans that connexions are not closed correctly.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/common-errors.html